# Is there a way to define to which group yammer OG should posted ?

Tags: yammer

When commenting using yammer embedd OG ((https://developer.yammer.com/connect/#commenting)) is there a way to define, to which group it should be posted through yammer embedd?

```
$('#yammerEmbeddDiv').empty();
yam.connect.embedFeed({
    container: '#yammerEmbeddDiv'
      , network: 'myNetwork.com'
    , feedType: 'open-graph'
, config: {
    header: false
 , footer: false
 , showOpenGraphPreview: false
}
    , objectProperties: {
        url: 'some URl'
      , type: 'page'
    }
});
```

Because by default it goes as an all company post.

Comment: The Rest service is riddled with undocumented features, so there is a good chance that something exists to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Use DefaultGroupId tag

```
yam.connect.embedFeed({
    container: '#yammerEmbeddDiv'
      , network: 'myNetwork.com'
    , feedType: 'open-graph'
, config: {
    header: false
 , footer: false
 , showOpenGraphPreview: false
, defaultGroupId: 'groupid'
}
    , objectProperties: {
        url: 'some URl'
      , type: 'page'
    }
});
```